# Getting started with FPGA development

Tags: c++, c, fpga

I would like to get an FPGA development board with the goal to emulate a CD-ROM drive.
My questions are:

- Is there any fpga that allows writing code in C/C++ and not VHDL?
- If you had to recommend a board , which one would that be ?
- Which book would you recommend to buy ?
- Is there anything else that i should know before going further ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting started with FPGA programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711306/getting-started-with-fpga-programming)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A) Well directly writing C++ code does not make sense, however you can emulate a processor and  write C/C++ to it. I have done this. I would recommend a starting kit from ALTERA don't buy something really expensive for starters.

B) http://www.altera.com/products/devkits/altera/kit-cyc2-2C20N.html This is pretty nice for example. I have implemented a dsp on it, using C.

Altera has the NIOS CPU which you can implement. It is not the easiest thing to do. You will need at least basic VHDL knowledge to do this.

C) [http://www.amazon.com/Designing-FPGAs-CPLDs-Bob-Zeidman/dp/1578201128](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578201128) covers the basics.

D) You should know digital architectures. C/C++ is way different than VHDL and you will not be able to harvest the true power of FPGA's until you know how the core components work. Adders, ALU's, MUX, DEMUX, MULTIPLIERS etc are integral parts of any digital circuit. You need to know how you can combine them in order to parallelize your solution and exploit the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

A) As an alternative approach, there are some C-like languages that compile down to VHDL or Verilog. See [C to HDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_to_HDL) on Wikipedia for details.

What a compiler for such a language usually produces is a customized circuit design for your specific "program". For instance, if you wanted to compute a*b+c*d+e*f, you might end up with a circuit that contains three multipliers and two adders and can run that computation for a different (a,b,c,d,e,f) tuple every cycle, sort of like a [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28computing%29).

I suppose it depends on what you want to do. For low level applications, a CPU is slower than a customized circuit, but it's definitely easier to program.

D) I agree with FailedDev. You should start with the basics, mess around with VHDL or [Verilog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog) and light up some LEDs (for instance, implement a binary counter).

Comment: Although there are indeed C to HDL compilers I would stay away from them , especially at start. You have little control over what the compiler will actually generate for you whereas with HDL you have direct control.